# Compute Maya Output Attr From Previous Frame's Outputs

Tags: api, time, maya

Does Maya allow one to compute the output attributes at frame N using the output attributes calculated at Frame (N-1) as inputs? With the proviso that at (e.g.) Frame 0 we don't look at the previous frame but use some sort of initial condition. Negative frames would be calculated by looking forward in time.

e.g. The translate of the ball at Frame N is computed to be the translate of the ball at Frame N-1 + 1cm higher. At frame zero the ball is given an initial translate of zero.

The DataBlock has a setContext function but the docs appear to forbid using that to do 'timed evaluation'. I could hit the attribute plugs directly and get value with a different time but that would be using inputs outside of the data block.

Is the Maya dependency API essentially timeless - only allowing calculation using the state at the current time? With the only solution to use animation curves which are also essentially timeless (their input state of key frames remaining the same regardless of the time)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple node connection is supposed to be updated on demand, ie for the 'current' frame.  It's supposed to be ahistorical -- you should be able to jump to a given frame directly and get a complete evaluation of the scene state without history.

If you need offset values you can use a [frame cache](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Nodes/frameCache-html.html) node to access a different point in the value stream.  You connect the attribute you want to lag to the frameCache's 'stream' plug, and then connect either the 'future' or 'past' attribute to the plug on your node.  The offset is applied by specifying the index value for the connections, ie, `frameCache1.past[5]` is 5 frames behind the value that was fed into the frameCache.

You can also do this in a less performant, but more flexible way by using an expression node.  The expression can poll an attribute value at a particular time by calling `getAttr()` with the `-t` flag to specify the time.  This is much slower to evaluate but lets you apply any arbitrary logic to the time offset you might want.